# Why don't we say Al Hanisim on other days?

Tags: tefilla, purim, bentching, miracle

We insert Al Hanisim on Purim and Channukah and that's fine -- each holiday is marked by a miracle. But why is its use limited to those days? Why don't we add it in to bentching and davening on Pesach which is defined by a central miracle (and a milchama that was fought on our behalf)?

Comment: Is this in addition to or instead of yaaleh veyavo?

Comment: In addition. The content of Al hanisim seems to apply to Pesach.

Comment: There is a minhag in some shuls to say Al haNisim on Yom haAtzmaut.

Comment: Al Hanisim is probably instead of ya’ale veyavo- ya’ale veyavo for chagim from the Torah, Al Hanisim for derabanan